# Formula to identify the first blank in a column and start the list over again

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Objective is to identify the first blank in a column, and then start the list again in another column, starting from that blank row.

[image: example].

My formula in column C is:

`=IFNA(XLOOKUP(IF(MATCH(TRUE,ISBLANK(B:B),0)<=A5+1,A5+2-MATCH(TRUE,ISBLANK(B:B),0),""),A:A,B:B),"")`

Although this works, it feels overly complicated for what it is doing. Can this be done in a simpler way? This Excel sheet won't be dealing with large quantities of data, so does not need to be overly efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UseVSTACK to stack blanks and the values.

```
=LET(
    RNG,DROP(B:B,1),
    FLT,FILTER(RNG,RNG<>""),
    VSTACK(INDEX("",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(FLT),,1,0)),FLT))
```

LET allows us to use variables to represent data.  so `DROP(B:B,1)` will put the values of all of column B minus the top row in the variable `RNG`.

From there we filter `RNG` to those that are not blank and put that array in `FLT`.  Then using `INDEX("",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(FLT),,1,0))` we create an array of empty strings the size of the filtered range. Then VSTACK puts the filtered range on the bottom.
[image]

Comment: I've never seen `LET()` before. I'm reading about it on the MS Support site, but mind adding a little info on what is happening? As "messy" as OP's formula is, I can follow it.  Yours looks to me like magic ;)  (What's `FLT`?)

Comment: @BruceWayne where you been?  Have not seen you around lately.

Comment: Without let the formula would be:  `=VSTACK(INDEX("",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(FILTER(DROP(B:B,1),DROP(B:B,1)<>"")),,1,0)),FILTER(DROP(B:B,1),DROP(B:B,1)<>""))`  So you can see why LET() is a game changer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!  I've been around, but work has gotten busier recently, and StackOverflow also basically nuked their mobile App, which is how I browsed SE primarily...so haven't been around as much, but I'm still there lurking.  (Note that by the time I find a question I can help with, you've typically already answered ;)  )

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=TOCOL(IF({1,0},"",DROP(TOCOL(B:B,1),1)),,1)
```

Or, a character shorter:

```
=TOCOL(REPT(DROP(TOCOL(B:B,1),1),{0,1}),,1)
```

Comment: I knew there was a formula out there that was better than the index().

Comment: I've revised my answer a bit @ScottCraner. I think two consecutive `TOCOL()` functions might work well here.

Comment: Well I can't upvote twice, or I would.  :)

Comment: Nice trick on the {0,1}. On the first formula it's amazing that the IF takes on 3 TRUE's like that. Funny how that works.